# Machine Learning and Binary Classification: f1 score is great in one class, terrible in another

Tags: python, machine-learning

I am using two methods (random tree and neural network) to calculate whether is person is suceptible to a certain disease, hence binary classification. After I run my code, I am getting a good f1-score for identitying the non-suceptible, for a terrible f1-score for identitying the suceptible:

```
          precision    recall  f1-score   support (Random Tree)

       0       0.86      0.99      0.92       711
       1       0.33      0.04      0.08       117

          precision    recall  f1-score   support (Neural Network)

       0       0.89      0.89      0.89       711
       1       0.31      0.30      0.30       117
```

I have tried a few things to increase the f-1 score, but to no avail:

1. Removing features that don't strongly correlate with the label
2. Removing features that have significant outliers
3. Increasing size of neural network (added extra layer, f1-score went from 0.23 to 0.30)

What are other possible reasons why my f1-score for predicting suceptibility is terrible?

```
#Random Forest
rf = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators = 199, random_state = 4)
rf.fit(X_train_scaled, y_train)
predictions = rf.predict(X_val_scaled)
y_val_hat_cat_rf = (rf.predict(X_val_scaled) > 0.5)
#Neural Network
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(Dense(11, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(7,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(4,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
hp_learning_rate = 0.01
model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=hp_learning_rate),
            loss=keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
            metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X_train_scaled,y_train,epochs=1000,verbose=0)
J_list = model.history.history['loss']
plt.plot(J_list)
val_acc_per_epoch = model.history.history['accuracy']
```

[image: TruePositive_vs_FalsePositive]

[image: Precision_vs_Recal]

[image: heatmap]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your random forest model is a regression one. You probably meant `RandomForestClassifier()`.

F-measure is threshold sensitive (which is unlikely to be 0.5 in this case). If F1 is truly your designated metric, you should study precision-recall curve for the proper threshold selection.

For a quick check you may also try `class_weight='balanced'` for `RandomForestClassifier`. Resampling your dataset would likely be excessive, but if you're only interested in the positive class, you may consider it. (This is frowned upon by statisticians, but so is using F1 for evaluation.)

Comment: Thank you! What about in the case of the neural network? Why does that one also give a bad precision and recall?

Comment: Not an expert on TF, but since you finish with a sigmoid, it seems logical to use `from_logits=False` (predictions being in 0..1 range).
Also, since sigmoid tends to underestimate the probability of rare events, the issue of choosing an optimal decision threshold still stands.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give that I try. Also, I attached the precision-recall and truePositive-falsePositive graphs. Is this just a case of bad data? If so, how could I clean up the data?

Comment: Removing features that don't strongly correlate with the label seems questionable: the relation might be nonlinear. Either way, it's hard to advise without seeing the data. Is this a public dataset?

Comment: Yes, it's quite a popular one actually: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/naveengowda16/logistic-regression-heart-disease-prediction. In my code, I removed 4 features: BPMeds, prevalentStroke, diabetes, and education. I plotted a heatmap, attached above. What's a threshold for a correlation to remove it? The smallest few are 0.00, 0.03, 0.04, and 0.06.

Comment: First of all, your target is discrete, so there's no reliable target correlations: the matrix might give you some ideas, but you'll need to run proper tests still. For example, `totChol` barely corellates with the target, but the mean difference between two classes is significant. You should also deal with features that correlate too much, like three different indicators of blood pressure, as those inflate your model variance. Overall, it seems handling extreme values is the key part here, as I was able to instantly improve metrics by 10% just by dropping around 1% outlying observations.

Comment: Thanks! Could you share part of your code concerning the part where you deal with the classes and outliers? I couldn't manage to get it myself because I'm still new to python.

Comment: I published my notebook draft at https://github.com/dx2-66/framingham_draft Result includes resampling, though it's not in any way necessary, some models fare even better without.
An [article](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2772442522000235/pdfft?md5=495b36cf73a412266c4a32f01abb77ee&pid=1-s2.0-S2772442522000235-main.pdf) caught my attention showing much better metrics - though I honestly have no idea how it scores around 0.5 even with a dummy classifier, it might not be the exact same dataset after all.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any particular reason why you chose BMI, glucose, and cholestrol to perform the tests on? Why not the other features? Also, for the outlier detection, is there any reason why the outlier_space is only BMI and glucose?

Comment: Those are just some examples, for a real solution you'd perform more extensive EDA for every feature, involving some domain knowledge perhaps. As about outlier space, I just picked a couple dimensions with visible tails and improving the metrics for me, feel free to try out various combos. Box or violin plots are helpful to get an idea on potential outlier candidates - once again, tedious as it is, EDA is the cornerstone of every DS project.

Comment: Just so I understand correctly, in your example, you remove all rows in the dataframe in which the Glucose-BMI is an outlier, even if the other features in that row are not outliers?

Comment: Correct, thats was the easiest way to deal with them.

Comment: Towards the end, how come the f1-score is still less than 50%?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247195/discussion-between-dx2-66-and-djdumpling).